# Modernization of a Makefile for an application with shared libraries

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that I've been using to compile my shared libraries and an executable for an APR based application.

```
APR_CONFIG    = $(shell which apr-1-config)
APU_CONFIG    = $(shell which apu-1-config)
BIN           = main
BIN_DIR       = bin
CC            = $(shell ${APR_CONFIG} --cc)
CFLAGS        = $(shell ${APR_CONFIG} --cflags --cppflags) -Wall
INCLUDES_APR  = $(shell ${APR_CONFIG} --includes)
INCLUDE_APR_X = -Iinclude
INCLUDES      = $(INCLUDES_APR) $(INCLUDES_MONGO) $(INCLUDES_APR_X)
LDFLAGS       = $(shell ${APR_CONFIG} --ldflags)
LDLIBS        = $(shell ${APR_CONFIG} --libs --link-ld) $(shell ${APU_CONFIG} --link-ld)
LIB_DIR       = lib

all: folders $(BIN)

folders:
    mkdir $(BIN_DIR) $(LIB_DIR)

$(BIN): main.o libimage libsound
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $<

libimage: image.o image_base.o image_focus.o
    $(CC) -o $(LIB_DIR)/$@.so -shared -fPIC $^

libsound: sound.o sound_spectrum.o sound_stereo.o
    $(CC) -o $(LIB_DIR)/$@.so -shared -fPIC $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $^

clean:
    $(RM) -rf *.o $(BIN_DIR) $(LIB_DIR)
```

What I would like to know is, how would you modernize this Makefile?
Critics are useful or beneficials but, please, be merciful with an old man :-)

Answer (score 3):

## cite your reference

I *guess* it is clear enough that we're talking about
[Apache Portable Runtime](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/modules.html)

```
APU_CONFIG = ...
```

This reference to
[APR-util](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr-util/1.6/modules.html) 
is more obscure, and warrants a `# comment`,
perhaps one that mentions an URL.

## re-evaluating

```
CC            = $(shell ${APR_CONFIG} --cc)
```

This is perfectly nice.
But I fear GNU make is likely doing more work than necessary when evaluating it.

I usually go with an `=` equal sign, where I can get away it, as it is simple.
Rather than `APR_CONFIG = ...`, prefer `APR_CONFIG := ...`,
so its value is frozen and won't be evaluated *again* when expanding `$(CC)`.
Or when evaluating `$(CFLAGS)`, and so on.

## pendantic

I love the `-Wall` lint flag on `CFLAGS`.
But it doesn't do *all* the linting that you might choose to sign up for.

Consider tacking on other linting flags, such as `-pedantic`.
Of course, that might imply a round of source cleanup
to get back to "silent running", so weigh whether that's worth it.

## language

There is more than one ANSI C language these days.
Few folks still write in the K&R C of the 1970's, or even the C of 1989.

I encourage you to explicitly specify `-std=c17` or similar.
Perhaps even `-std=gnu17`.

BTW, the `INCLUDE_APR_X = -Iinclude` surprises me, but hey, what do I know?
I imagine you really do need it.
Maybe tack on a `# comment` explaining what's going on with those
eXtra header files, for example, describing where they came from
and how they get installed.

In any event, the omnibus definition of `INCLUDES` is lovely,
and I thank you for it.

## phony targets

```
all: folders $(BIN)
```

This is pretty bog standard, good.

Consider explicitly listing `folders` as a .PHONY target.
Consider defining `FOLDERS = $(BIN_DIR) $(LIB_DIR)`
so there's no phony target at all.

Consider making it use `mkdir -p`, so it's fine if *one*
of the directories already exists.
(That's just a habitual switch I use in makefiles,
striving for idempotency even in the face of recent Makefile edits.)

The business of `$(BIN)` being `main` confuses me,
and is very much bound up in whether we're going the phony route or not.

Consider defining a symbol that mentions the `main` binary plus both `*.so`'s,
and put it after `all:`.
Then you could create non-phony targets that do three link edits.
This would set you up for using the same symbol in the `clean` recipe.

Don't get me wrong, it's not that I'm down on phonies,
e.g. `$ make lint` or the venerable `$ make clean`.
It's just that in *this* Makefile I find myself wishing for actual
pathnames in targets, rather than abbreviated aliases.

## main

```
$(BIN): main.o libimage libsound
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $<
```

Sorry, you lost me there.
But I imagine it works?

I am reading
[the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html):

> $<
>
> The name of the first prerequisite....

In the interest of clarity I tend to use that
when there's just a single prerequisite listed,
preferring e.g. `$(OBJS)` when there's multiple.
Here, the `libimage` & `libsound` deps are muddying the waters for me.
And again, using abbreviated phony target names is not improving clarity.

If the `main` binary gets dynamically linked against
either `libimage.so` or `libsound.so` at runtime,
I am not yet seeing such details, I don't see the relationship to `main`.

Anyway, I really like how `$^` is being consistently used.
The `%.o` rule is nice.

---

In its current form this code appears to achieve its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: A _standard_ way of dealing with `folders` is making them [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html).

Answer (score 1):

None of these rules actually create the targets as promised:

> ```
> $(BIN): main.o libimage libsound
>     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@ $<
>
> libimage: image.o image_base.o image_focus.o
>     $(CC) -o $(LIB_DIR)/$@.so -shared -fPIC $^
>
> libsound: sound.o sound_spectrum.o sound_stereo.o
>     $(CC) -o $(LIB_DIR)/$@.so -shared -fPIC $^
> ```

The first creates `$(BIN_DIR)/$(BIN)`, the second `$(LIB_DIR)/libimage.so` and the third `$(LIB_DIR)/libsound.so`.  But the contract with Make is that `test -e $@` is true at the end of each (non-phony) rule.

---

This pattern rule is inferior to the built-in, and should not be specified:

> ```
> %.o: %.c
>     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $^
> ```

Instead, we should simply `CFLAGS += $(INCLUDES)`

---

The variables which spawn shell comments when expanded (i.e. containing `$(shell …)` probably ought to have those evaluated just once, by using `:=` instead of `=`.

---

> ```
> clean:
>     $(RM) -rf *.o $(BIN_DIR) $(LIB_DIR)
> ```

`$(RM)` already includes `-f`, so only `-r` needs specifying.

We're missing `.PHONY: clean` (as this rule doesn't create a file called `clean`.

We're missing `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` to ensure partial output doesn't linger and cause future builds to fail.